# Stuck at 36th exercise of Learn Python the Hard Way

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code I have written for [Learn Python the Hard Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321884914) exercise 36. But I am not able to run the code in the `door_1` function. If I choose 3 as an option and then left or right anything which is then stored in dir, the output is "lion ate you", no matter what I type.

```
from sys import exit #importing module from lib

def Tadaa():
    print "This is a place where you will get a surprise"
    next = int(raw_input("Enter any number from 1-10 :"))
    if next <= 10:  
        if next % 2 == 0 :
            print "You will be buying me a shake :)."
        else :
            print "You will be getting a shake by me."
    else :
        print "Do it correctly."

def door_1():
    print "There are 3 doors . Choose any door from the the remaining three doors"
    print "Lets hope for the best "
    next = raw_input("Enter your option :")
    if next == "1":
        print "abc "
    elif next == "2": 
        print "abc"
    elif next == "3":
        print "You have entered 3rd door ."
        print "Here are 2 doors one on left and one on right."

        dir = raw_input("Choose which door do you wnat to enter :")

        if dir == "left" or "Left":
            print "Lion ate you . You are dead ."
        elif dir == "right" or "Right" :
            print "You will be getting a surprise"
            Tadaa()
        else :
            print "abc"
    else :
        print "abc"

def door_2():
    print "There are two doors A and B which will decide your fate"

    next = raw_input("Enter the door ")

    if next == "A" or "a":
        door_1()            
    elif next == "B" or "b":
        print "You are back from where you have started"
        start()
    else :
        print "I got no idea what that means."
        exit(0)

def start():
    print "You are in dark room"
    print "There is a door to your right and left ."
    print "Which one do you take"

    next = raw_input("> ")

    if next == "Right" or "right":
        door_2()
    elif next == "Left" or "left":
        door_1()
    else :
        print "abc"
start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your statement:

```
if dir=="left" or "Left":
```

What you want is

```
if dir=="left" or dir=="Left":
```

In effect, what just doing `or "Left"` is doing, is checking whether a string that you've just created exists or not. Put another way, its similar to:

```
x='Left'
if x:
```

X does exist, so `if X` is `True`.

The crux here is to always evaluate statements in quantum, and when you're using `and` in conjunction with `or` statements, make sure you use brackets to be explicit. `if statement_one or statement_two`.

Comment: But if you will see start() function you will see I have done the same with next statement as well but it does run

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure off hand, but what I can tell you for a fact is the way you are evaluating `if` statements is not correct :) Do it properly as demonstrated above and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: If you get to know about the next statement do let me know :)

Comment: Just, as I said, fix it all up. You should use `if next=='Right' or next=='right'`, for example. I dont know why it seems to be working fine now, but I'm sure its buggy code and its only working by a fluke. Debugging code is fine, debugging accidentally functional code is quite hard sometimes.